# Jquery:Asynchronous how to load content sequentially

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I am having a html page with the following jquery script. It uses $.get to get http://locahost and inside callback function appends a link to `<pre>` element. All this is running inside a loop.The loop runs 100 times, 100 links are created.It takes some time to complete 100 loops. Meanwhile if i want to click on any link it does not allow to click. What i am looking, is while the loop continues, i should be able to click on the links it already created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost/~simha/viralvideos-master/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<pre>   </pre>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: true
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            console.log("b = " + i);
            fburl1 = "http://localhost/";
            console.log($('pre'));
            $.get(fburl1, function (data) {
                console.log("a = " + i);
                $('pre').append("<a href=\"localhost\">\"hare\""+i+"<a\/><p><\/p>");
            })
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the output is

```
"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100

"hare"100
```

i want it

```
"hare"1

"hare"2
..

"hare"100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid synchronous AJAX requests**.

Reason ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)):

> synchronous requests block the execution of code which creates "freezing" on the screen and an unresponsive user experience.

So in your case removing below setting should make it work better:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false // <--- remove this
});
```

**UPD**. You can also scope iteration index so the it is correct for each iteration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        var fburl1 = "http://localhost/";

        // Create a closure with scoped i value passed as index inside
        (function(index) {
            $.get(fburl1, function(data) {
                console.log("a = " + index);
                $('pre').append("<a href=\"localhost\">\"hare\"" + index + "<a\/><p><\/p>");
            });
        })(i);
    }
})
```

Comment: But i want the $.get to load one after another, else the content get mixed.

Comment: What is the solution. can you tell me.

Comment: What content gets mixed can you update you code to show what content you are loading so I can give better solution?

Comment: i am appending a link to pre element inside the $.get. I am not using any data from the response. You can see the code.

Comment: So what content then gets mixed? You are loading the same content 100 times and appending the same link, so the order then doesn't matter. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Also. if i want to do anyting on the data inside $.get it will also do in sequence or not

Comment: This is not guaranteed because response could come out of order. For this you would need to modify your code to load next portion of data after previous is loaded For example one solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/nO5dJB491sXZpVMnCz40?p=info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103419/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-dfsq).